# Should I copy-edit duplicate posts?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Duplicate posts (to some extent) are good, as they provide more targets for the unwitting Googler to stumble across when looking stuff up.  However, should I avoid copy-editing those posts?  Does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about duplicate questions asked accidentally, right? Then do copy edit them.

Comment: @Matthew That's the opposite of what I said. Even if it's a closed question, it should be copy-edited (I assume that means "fix typos" etc.)

Comment: I think I just misread, not that it was confusing.  Fixing typos is fine, but I would avoid rewording very much.